# Confusion regarding usage of 'a and b' in an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

In an ellipse I understand that the terms $a$ and $b$ are used to refer to the lengths of semi major and semi minor axes respectively. In my textbook there are different formulae for each of the cases; when $a>b$ and vice versa. However my teacher has said that it is okay to always take the (semi) length of axis along $x$-axis (I am talking about standard ellipses) as $a$ and correspondingly along $y$ as $b$.
Which convention should I follow?

Comment: See [Ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse).

Comment: The major axis is always larger than the minor one. Therefore it is not clear what do you mean by saying " when > and vice versa". If "vice versa" is possible the author of the textbook uses another definition for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I guess a and b are just variables and do not represent semi major and minor axes as such.

Comment: Sometimes you don't care which axis is longer; eg, maybe you're interested in the "stretched circle" *shape* but not where the foci are located. You have to call their lengths *something*, and it's reasonable to associate $a$ with $x$, and $b$ with $y$, so you have "horizontal/vertical" axes instead of "major/minor". It's not unlike having the quadratic equation $bx^2+cx+a=0$: the Quadratic Formula still applies to find $x$, but it'll look like $\frac{1}{2b}(-c\pm \sqrt{c^2-4ab})$; you have to pay attention to the *roles* of the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, not their alphabetical order.

Comment: See, as one example among many, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3442503/409), where I specifically refer to "horizontal" and "vertical" semi-axes (although I use "radii", a term I like better).

Comment: The characterization of an ellipse via major an minor axes is universal. It does not depend on a certain coordinate system. Contradistinctively, the system proposed by your teacher has meaning only in a Cartesian coordinate system with a special choice of the axes.

Comment: But if a>b, does that make it necessary that the ellipse is wider along the axis and correspondingly if a<b should the ellipse always be wider along the y axis? And does the same apply to transverse and conjugate hyperbolas respectively?